# How to check maximum available memory in NTAG216?

Tags: android, tags, nfc, mifare, fingerprinting

How do I determine the maximum page where I can write in NTAG216? I can't find any methods [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.html) that will let me check the maximum available memory. Also according to the documentation:

> The next 36 pages are the user read/write area.

Does that mean I can only write up to page 36? I tried writing up to page 50 and it doesn't give any error.

I was using NFC Tools to check the maximum memory but once I wrote bytes starting page 4, the data about the maximum memory became unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I determine the maximum page where I can write in NTAG216?

If you know that the tag is an NXP NTAG**216** tag, then you would determine the size of the tag by looking into [the datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf). The datasheet tells you that an NTAG216 tag is organized into 231 pages, where pages 4 to 225 are user memory (i.e. the memory that you can freely use for data).

#### According to the documentation, "*the next 36 pages are the user read/write area.*" Does that mean I can only write up to page 36?

Carefully read [that documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.html). It tells you that "*the first 4 pages are for OTP, manufacturer data, and locking bits*". And that "*the next 36 pages are the user read/write area.*" Consequently, this means that the pages of the user memory are numbered from 4 to 40 (= 4 + 36). However, the documentation also clearly states that this only applies to **MIFARE Ultralight C** (**MF0ICU2**), which is a completely different tag type.

#### How do I determine if the tag actually is a NTAG216 tag?

You can use the GET_VERSION command to check this. If the GET_VERSION command succeeds and indicates the characteristic version information of NTAG216, you can assume that the tag actually is a NTAG216 tag.

```
byte[] GET_VERSION = new byte[] { (byte)0x60 };
byte[] result = nfca.transceive(GET_VERSION);
if ((result != null) && (result.length == 8)) {
    // GET_VERSION command successful
    if ((result[0] == 0) && (result[1] == (byte)0x04) && (result[2] == (byte)0x04)) {
        // tag is NTAG
        if ((result[3] == (byte)0x02) && (result[4] == (byte)0x01) && (result[5] == (byte)0x00) && (result[7] == (byte)0x03)) {
            if (result[6] == (byte)0x13) {
                // tag is NTAG216
            } else if (result[6] == (byte)0x11) {
                // tag is NTAG215
            } else if (result[6] == (byte)0x0F) {
                // tag is NTAG213
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks as always! Great answer.

Comment: Just to verify, I can start writing on page 4 ending on page 225, since I can write 4 bytes per page that means I have a total of 4*(225-4+1)  bytes right?